# Compare and Filter Object Array in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

How to determine the cheapest and fastest rate and get the value in single object.

- `cheapest` is determined by using `netfee` having `least value`
- `fastest` is determined by using `speed` having `less days`
- `best` is determined by using `amount` having `highest value`

I got stuck and let know is any alternative solution.

```
var result = getValue(obj);
getValue(obj){
 var cheapest= Math.min.apply(Math, obj.map(function (el) {
        return el.netfee;
  })); 
  var best= Math.max.apply(Math, obj.map(function (el) {
        return el.amount;
  }));
  var res= Object.assign({}, cheapest, best);
return res;
}
```

```
var obj=[
{ 
  id: "sample1",
  netfee: 10,
  speed: "1days",
  amount: "100"
},
{
 id: "sample2",
 netfee: 6,
 speed: "2days",
 amount: "200"
},
{
 id: "sample3",
 netfee: 4,
 speed: "3days",
 amount: "50"
}
]

Expected Output:

Cheapest : Sample 3

Fastest: Sample 1

Best: Sample 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

so simple..

```js
var obj=[
  { id: "sample1", netfee: 10, speed: "1days", amount: "100" },
  { id: "sample2", netfee: 6,  speed: "2days", amount: "200" },
  { id: "sample3", netfee: 4,  speed: "3days", amount:  "50" }
];

var
  cheapest = obj.reduce((acc, cur)=>(acc.netfee < cur.netfee ? acc : cur)).id,
  fastest  = obj.reduce((acc, cur)=>(parseInt(acc.speed,10) < parseInt(cur.speed,10) ? acc : cur)).id,
  best     = obj.reduce((acc, cur)=>(Number(acc.amount) > Number(cur.amount) ? acc : cur)).id;

console.log( "cheapest =", cheapest  )
console.log( "fastest  =", fastest  )
console.log( "best     =", best  )
```

[edit]:
Thanks to **muka.gergely** for his remark on `parseInt(acc.speed,10)` *(specify to use base 10)*
 for memo : `console.log(parseFloat('0.7 days')`  return =  0.7

Comment: Don’t use **parseInt** without setting the base, like **parseInt(acc.speed, 10)**. It saves you a lot of debugging time and “what the heck is going on!?” type questions.

Comment: @muka.gergely I thought if the `string` parameter of the *parseInt* method starts with anything apart from *0x* or *0*, then the `radix` parameter is 10 by default? ️

Comment: That may be the case, but nothing ensures that in the snippet - you can have 0.5days as speed (as far as this code allows), and it’s better safe than sorry :)

Comment: Oh yes, you got a reason :)

Answer (score 1):

You can apply this hack, to have the answer as in the expected output:

```js
var obj = [
  {
    id: "sample1",
    netfee: 10,
    speed: "1days",
    amount: "100"
  },
  {
    id: "sample2",
    netfee: 6,
    speed: "2days",
    amount: "200"
  },
  {
    id: "sample3",
    netfee: 4,
    speed: "3days",
    amount: "50"
  }
];

var result = getValue(obj);

function getValue(obj) {
  var cheapest = obj.reduce((acc, next) => acc.netfee < next.netfee ? acc : next).id;
  var fastest = obj.reduce((acc, next) => parseInt(acc.speed) < parseInt(next.speed) ? acc : next).id;
  var best = obj.reduce((acc, next) => +acc.amount > +next.amount ? acc : next).id;

  var res = Object.assign({}, {
    cheapest,
    fastest,
    best
  });

  return res;
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: `return { cheapest, fastest, best };`  do the same  ;)

Comment: for info `+acc.amount` is slower than `Number(acc.amount)`

Comment: @MrJ Really?? Well jsperf.com told me otherwise, check it out [here](https://jsperf.com/aminukano/1).

Comment: ? I do not think that kind of performance test is valid in this case. this test should be done for less than 10 loops, and using numbers from a table, and with negative values; so we could better judge the work of the interpreter JS, without it being able to launch an optimizer of operations

Comment: Oh yes, I understand your perspective.